# Redmine 5.0.2 で SAML 認証プラグインの読み込み時に NameError

Tags: ruby, redmine

Docker版Redmine(5.0.2)に、[saml認証のプラグイン](https://github.com/davintoo/redmine_omniauth_saml) を導入しようとしています。

`bundle install` , `bundle exec rake` は完了し、導入自体は成功しているように見受けられますが、`/usr/src/redmine/config/initializers` に設定ファイルを配置すると以下のエラーとなり、Redmineの起動に失敗してしまいます。

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant RedmineOmniauthSaml
```

設定ファイルには以下のように記述しています。

```
RedmineOmniauthSaml::Base.configure do |config|
  config.saml = {
...
```

うまくclassを読み込めていないのかと思うのですが、Redmine 5系となり、記述方法等が変更になったのでしょうか。

環境はRedmine 5.0.2, Ruby 3.1.2-p20, Rails 6.1.6 です。
尚、同じプラグイン、設定ファイルを用いて、Redmineの4系で試行しましたが、Redmine自体は問題なく起動します。

こちらはruby, rails等の理解があまりなく、ヒントを頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。
/usr/src/redmine/config/initializers に配置する設定ファイルの頭に

```
require Rails.root.join('plugins/redmine_omniauth_saml/lib/redmine_omniauth_saml')
```

とすることで、無事Redmineが起動するようになりました。
（設定値が正しく反映されているかは別として）

ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

参照しているリポジトリも [アーカイブされたリポジトリ](https://github.com/chrodriguez/redmine_omniauth_saml) からフォークしたもののようですが、別のフォークしたリポジトリで Redmine 5.x 向けの修正を行っているものがあるようなので、代わりにこちらを試してみてはどうでしょうか。

https://github.com/fortinet-solutions-cse/redmine_omniauth_saml

[Update class name / scope for RM v5](https://github.com/fortinet-solutions-cse/redmine_omniauth_saml/commit/6860912901a08d4bdc45e3de9023221b28dfd8d2) (最新のコミット: 抜粋)

```rb
-      user_attributes = Redmine::OmniAuthSAML.user_attributes_from_saml omniauth
+      user_attributes = RedmineOmniAuthSaml.user_attributes_from_saml omniauth
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
こちらのフォークされたリポジトリ(For V5向けと思われるもの)については、すべて試しました。bundle exec rake までうまく完了できたものが、質問させていただいたプラグインのみでしたので、こちらを利用しました。
引き続き、他のプラグインでも試みてみます。

Comment: ご自身で試したことは漏らさず質問に記載しておくと、やり取りがスムーズになると思います。 / 代わりにこちら https://github.com/yoshiokaCB/redmine_omniauth_saml はどうでしょうか？ Redmine 互換の RedMica 向けとのことですが、Redmine 5.0 向けの修正を行っているとのことです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
yoshiokaCB / redmine_omniauth_saml はじめ、Redmine5向けの修正が入っているforkされたバージョン以下について試してみましたが、
nhochdrei / redmine_omniauth_saml
fortinet-solutions-cse / redmine_omniauth_saml
kaihei777 / redmine_omniauth_saml_azure
nayuta / redmine_omniauth_saml
radicalgrimoire / redmine_omniauth_saml

こちらの環境では、いずれも  bundle exec rake に失敗してしまい、導入することができませんでした。